# connection refused from host machine

Tags: nginx, vagrant

I am using vagrant with virtualbox as provider. Within my guest system I have nginx installed and configured. 
nginx is serving some static files from a folder and exposing them on port 80. That works fine. If I call `curl localhost` within the guest machine I get the answer I was supposed to receive.

I have a very simple vagrantfile, which you can see below. I forward port 80 to port 8080, but from the host machine I cant access that page via `localhost:8080`.

I already disabled the firewall in the guest machine without any success.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # VirtualBox Settings: Give it a little bit more memory
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "768"]
  end

  # Base Image: CentOS 7.0 x86_64
  config.vm.box = "jayunit100/centos7"

  # Use Vagrant's default insecure key (~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key)
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  # Add port forwarding for node-inspector
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080 # node-inspector

  # Map project directory
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/server/"

  # Provisioning Shell Script
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant-setup/base.sh"
end
```

If I call `curl -v 'http://localhost:8080'` from the host system I get told that the connection got refused. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: might be tricky to debug - if iptable is disabled on the guest. anything running on 8080 on the host ? jus try with another port - would give a try with http://127.0.0.1:8080 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to disable my firewall on the host machine with `iptables -F`

Comment: I have kind of same problem. I asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295776/cannot-access-localhost8080-from-laravel , could you help me with that? I am running on Mac.