# Cannot access localhost:8080 from laravel

Tags: laravel, vagrant, guzzle, homestead

I have a PHP application running on homestead box. This application makes calls to another app that is running on glassfish on my localhost:8080.

When PHP application sends the request to localhost:8080, I am getting following error:

```
ConnectException in RequestException.php line 49:
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Still I can make calls to localhost:8080 from web browser.Anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how your application is running in Homestead (which by default is available on `192.168.10.10` and is forwarded to also be accessible on `localhost:8000`) your application running on Glassfish will not have access to it using `localhost:8080`. This is because `localhost` in your vagrant box (Homestead) is not actually the same `localhost` as on the host machine.

What you could do is grab the ip address from the host machine and connect to it from your application running in Homestead.

Comment: Other application is running on Glassfish in my local machine; the ip address 127.0.0.1 exists in /etc/hosts in vagrant box. (I ssh to homestead to check it). So what do you mean by getting the ip address of the host machine? thanks!

Comment: Yes `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` is always the 'current' machine. So on your host/local machine it points to your host/local machine, in your vagrant box (Homestead) it points to your vagrant box. Homestead by default uses `192.168.10.10` as it's 'external' ip address, what your local machine uses really depends on a lot of different things. Usually your router assigns it for you. How to retrieve that ip address depends on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I could solve the problem. Vagrant is the guest machine running on my localhost as host machine. To access host from guest, you need to use gateway from VB.

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/310697/connect-to-the-host-machine-from-a-virtualbox-guest-os/310745#310745) which helped me to access my application on localhost.